# how to terminate execution of the current class?

Tags: php

I am trying to embed data from external resources.

For each website that I have api access, I created a specific-Class to do the data fetching.

The rest of websites will use one general-Class.

So, at the very begining of the general-Class, if a URL pattern matches any of the URL that I already coded in the specific-Class, I want to exit the general-class immedietly.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using some intermediate step to intercept URLs and then include/use the class or not as required.